# When Typing Into Form Inputs User Experiences Abnormal Lag

Tags: php, html, performance, web-testing

When the user types into my search engine, which is a form on my website that is just an input text field, the user experiences extreme lag between entering a letter on their keyboard and the letter appearing on the screen in the text field. The user's complaint is BEFORE she hits search or presses the enter button on her keyboard (so her complaint has nothing to do with submission of the form...). She says it is my input field that is causing the lag. How do I trouble shoot this? I do not experience this on my end in testing and no other user has complained about the speed of my website. What are some details from her I need to test this? Like do I need to know her operating system? Is a lag of this sort more deeper than "the website is experiencing high traffic"? I am unsure of all the factors that play into keyboard to screen lag. I want to ask her if she has a key logger, but the user claims it is only on my website.

I am searching the issue currently and need suggestions on if this is a code issue or a user issue. In testing I do not experience this issue when I type into the search engine on my machine. I have tested this in firefox and chrome.

I would really appreciate some google search terms, so I can read up on this problem myself. I am also open to whatever suggestions you guys have.

Comment: A good place to start would be are you executing a script onkeypress, or something?

Comment: The user might have one or more add-ins affecting input fields.

Comment: @Chipster No, this is a basic search. When the user hits enter it will submit the form or when the user hits the search button, but they have to do one of those two actions. The user complaint is just when she types into the input field. :( I don't experience this lag when I test.

Comment: @Dave Thank you! I will ask the user what add ons she has and do some research with that. I didn't even think of add ons! I was thinking maybe she has a keylogger. Haha!

Comment: @LadyLearningWebDev, okay. Well, next you can see what browser they are using and google common efficiency problems with that browser.