# Inconsistent input lag in the input field in a React App

Tags: reactjs, forms, input, lag

I'm experiencing a similar issue with this question: [When Typing Into Form Inputs User Experiences Abnormal Lag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54427162/when-typing-into-form-inputs-user-experiences-abnormal-lag)

Basically I have a regular input field in my React App and it works totally normal on my end. However, I received messages from other users saying that they experienced lagging while typing in the input field. I could not figure out why since we are using the app and even the same browser (tried on Chrome, Safari etc.) Does anyone have any idea? Thank you!

How it looks normally (aka what is expected to happen)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NIo14.gif)

How it looks with lagging (Only for some users)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0MS7I.gif)

Answer (score 0):

- Does it calls api on typing? if yes, consider to debounce the typing input. It usually can be done with setTimeout.

```js
const timeoutRef = React.useRef(null)

const handleChangeInput = ev => {
  const inputValue = ev.target.value;
  setInput(inputValue);
  clearTimeout(timeoutRef.current);
  timeoutRef.current = setTimeout(() => apiSearch(inputValue), 500);
}
```

- If it's a rendering performance issue, consider to use uncontrolled input. Using the form library like [React Hook Form](https://www.react-hook-form.com/) also can help. Check how many times the page is rendered on input change.
- If not, probably some chrome extension on the client somehow worsen the performance.

Comment: Hi Erwin, thanks for replying!
- It does not call any api on typing
- I am actually using react-hook-form! I used it for all input fields in my app to control the values. Somehow only this input field has the lagging issue for certain users

Comment: i see, have you checked how many times the page rendered on type an input? if nothing's wrong with the times rendered and the issue only happen on that one specific user, then the issue is on the client device resource / browser.